# QML, dynamically adding elements to a listview

Tags: listview, qml, qtquick2

I need some help with adding elements into a qml listview, i have a textarea and a button that will add the textarea text into a listview item when is pressed, here's my attempt:

```
Component {
    id: delegate
    Item {
        width: 200; height: 28
        Label {
            text: score
        }
    }
}

ListView {
     id: p1scores
     model: p1model
     delegate: delegate
     anchors.top: p1name.bottom
     anchors.topMargin: units.gu(1)
}

ListModel {
     id: p1model
     ListElement { score: "0" }
}

TextArea {
     id: p1input
     width: units.gu(8)
     height: units.gu(3)
     horizontalAlignment: TextEdit.AlignHCenter
     inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
     contentHeight: units.gu(60)
     anchors.topMargin: units.gu(8)
}

Button {
     id:p1button
     text: i18n.tr("Add")
     width: units.gu(8)
     onClicked: {
        p1model.append({"score": p1input.text})
        p1input.text = ""
     }
}
```

i tried appending it but doesn't shows up in the listview... any help?

Comment: in your p1button onClicked, you cleared the text in TextArea *before* adding the text to the ListModel, of course the text wouldn't show up.

Comment: The text still doesn't shows up, i think its a problem with the delegate... (edited the question)

Comment: I'm not sure but... change your `delegate` Component id to something else, because when you use `delegate: delegate` in your ListView, it assume is `delegate: p1scores.delegate`, so it bind back to itself.

Comment: i found the problem, it was that i didn't specified a height to the listview and apparently the default is the size of a single item...

Answer (score 15):

Try without quotes around 'score', like this:

```
onClicked: {
    p1model.append({score: p1input.text})
    p1input.text = ""
}
```